# Copying cell colors to another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, colors, vlookup

My active sheet (let's call it Sheet1) will be main for all users to edit and view.
User 1 only needs to view half the data in Sheet1 at a time so I've created a Sheet2 to only display the data that User 1 needs by using Vlookup. The data moves but not the color of the cells.

How can I get the color of the cells to move also? The column numbers are not consistent ex. column C,E, F, J and M with rows 1 - 99.

On another post, I saw a similar scenario but could not get it to work for me with multiple columns and rows. Here is the other post [Copy cell colour from one worksheet to another based on cell reference in second sheet](https://superuser.com/questions/1444148/copy-cell-colour-from-one-worksheet-to-another-based-on-cell-reference-in-second)

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide some sample data?

The lookup function cannot obtain the cell format at the same time, the only way is to use copy (except VBA).

You need to add some auxiliary columns to sheet2 first, such as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5... and then use lookup in sheet1 to get 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.., and then sort " 1, 2, 3, 4, 5" in sheet1, copy the part where sheet1 and sheet2 have the same fields. In this way, the data pasted in sheet2 can maintain the cell format at the same time.